# NiFi ExecuteSQL change types for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, apache-nifi, avro

I have sqlite files that have incorrect datatypes defined to some fields hence the ExecuteSQL shows type error.

How do I provide the correct datatype to the processor for it to execute the select query correctly?

[image]

Comment: what's the actual error/exception message? Please add it to the question, thanks.

Comment: ok added the error message

Comment: You need to Cast those column/columns, please refer this - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Apache-Nifi-ExecuteSQL-processor-error-org-apache-avro/td-p/176183

Comment: Try using `CAST or ROUND` sqlite function for data type conversion